# Android: how can I control volume of ring and music in the same time?

Tags: android, audio

I have problem, I use Text To Speech and also play some sounds with MediaPlayer. I understand that if I want to control volume of MediaPlayer I must set:

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

but I noticed that my TextToSpeech is controlled by ring volume. So when I set `STREAM_MUSIC` I can set sfx volume but can't set TTS volume and vice versa when I don't set `STREAM_MUSIC`. Question is - how can I control both volumes at same time or how can I set my tts stream as a music. Eventually please give me some other ideas.

---

edit1:

So this is my SoundManager class that I init in my Singleton

```
public class SoundManager {
private static boolean allowed = true;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

public SoundManager(Context context) {
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
}

public boolean isAllowed() {
    return allowed;
}

public static void setAllowed(boolean allowed) {
    SoundManager.allowed = allowed;
}

public void Play(Context context, String text) {
    if(allowed) {
        int identifier = context.getResources().getIdentifier(text, "raw", context.getPackageName());
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, identifier);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}

public void destroy(){
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
}
```

And this is my Speaker Class:

```
public class Speaker implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

private TextToSpeech tts;

private static boolean ready = false;

private static boolean allowed = true;

public Speaker(Context context){
    tts = new TextToSpeech(context, this);
}

public boolean isAllowed(){
    return allowed;
}

public static boolean isReady() {
    return ready;
}

public static void setAllowed(boolean allowed){
    Speaker.allowed = allowed;
}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
        ready = true;
        int result = 0;
        result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US); // Language set
        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            ready = false;
        }
    }else{
        ready = false;
    }
}

public void speak(String text){

    // Speak only if the TTS is ready
    // and the user has allowed speech

    if(ready && allowed) {
        HashMap<String, String> hash = new HashMap<String,String>();
        hash.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION));
        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, hash);
    }
}

public void pause(int duration){
    tts.playSilence(duration, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
}

// Free up resources
public void destroy(){
    tts.shutdown();
}
```

in my activities `onCreate` I put on 
`setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);`
and then I can manage the sounds volume control but not TTS.

Comment: can You please post what You have done?

Comment: all this seems to be ok, please post where You change the volume

Comment: Well I didn't set any methods for volume buttons yet. So You say I have to write them by myself, theres no way I can do this diffrently?

Comment: Oh I found this @CapDroid:"The TTS SDK doesn't have any pause functionality that I know of. But you could use synthesizeToFile() to create an audio file that contains the TTS output. Then, you would use a MediaPlayer object to play, pause, and stop playing the file. Depending on how long the text string is, it might take a little longer for audio to be produced because the synthesizeToFile() function would have to complete the entire file before you could play it, but this delay should be acceptable for most applications." but that would suck to store the file :D

Comment: Omg this was really bad question :D also the solution to this was in front of my eyes hash.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION)); just change the STREAM_NOTIFICATION to STREAM_MUSIC... how the hell I missed that? :D

Comment: Good post, but how do I accomplish this with API 21? - speak(CharSequence text, int queueMode, Bundle params, String utteranceId);